# Searching a Tree for a certain value

Tags: java

I need help searching a binary tree with int data(not necessarily binary search tree) and see if an element is in the tree. If it is in the tree return the reference and if it is not found return null. This is the code I have so far.

```
Node search(TreeNode root, int key){
  if(root == null){
    return null;
    }  
   search(root.left, key);
   search(root.right, key); 

if(root.right.data === key || root.left.data == key){
     return root;
   }else{ 
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @Tyymo - What ? you don't have magic powers to guess the problem ? Baah.

Comment: Is the code correct? will this code still check the root node to see if its identical to the key?

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Although the case is quite obvious, the OP must be able to phrase the issue clearly, for the sake of future questions.

Comment: Im sorry about the misunderstanding, Im just confused about recursion and I want to make sure this is the correct way to send back a node if found.

Comment: @user3063666 I would love to help. However, why did you not run some tests by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `search(root.left, key);`. That is great. Except that if the element you are searching for is indeed in the left branch of the current Node, nothing happens. The method keeps executing, no matter what the recursive call has reported. You need to keep that data and handle it appropriately.

Therefore you should do something like this:

```
Node search(TreeNode root, int key){
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (root.data == key)
        return root;

    Node n;

    n = search(root.left, key);
    if (n != null)
        return n;

    n = search(root.right, key);
    if (n != null)
        return n;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much good sir! So whenever we are returning we must save the data in a variable?

Comment: I will not use the term 'ever', since it is too general. For this specific algorithm, you should save the return value from the function, because that is a good "strategy". I recommend you to plan your "strategy" which will solve the problem on paper first, before writing the actual code. At least at the beginning.

Comment: Why do we return null at the end of the method, I thought this was already done when we hit the base case

Comment: Consider the case where `root` exists, however its `data` is not equal to `key` and it has no children.